# Windows phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have tried to choose a contact from the contact list in a windows phone 7 app and display it in a textbox. Now I want to save that contact in that textbox for future use of that application. How I can save a chosen contact from a windows phone in a text box. This is the code I tried.

```
 PhoneNumberChooserTask phoneNumberChooserTask;
 phoneNumberChooserTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
 phoneNumberChooserTask.Completed += phoneNumberChooserTaskOnCompleted;
 phoneNumberChooserTask.Show();

 private void phoneNumberChooserTaskOnCompleted(object sender, PhoneNumberResult phoneNumberResult) 
 {
     if (phoneNumberResult.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
     {
         textBox1.Text = phoneNumberResult.PhoneNumber;
     }
 }
```

Suggest some code samples.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a settings object in isolated storage where you can store settings and data

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

private void phoneNumberChooserTaskOnCompleted(object sender, PhoneNumberResult phoneNumberResult) 
 {
     if (phoneNumberResult.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
     {
         textBox1.Text = phoneNumberResult.PhoneNumber;
         //add your contact to settings
         settings.Add("phoneNumber", phoneNumberResult.PhoneNumber)
     }
 }


//on page load, load the saved number from settings
if(settings.Contains("phoneNumber"))  
    textBox1.Text = settings["phoneNumber"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: When I try to reselect the contact the program breaks and it shows an exception "Value does not fall within the expected range". How  I  can remove the previously selected contact and choose new one.

Comment: use `settings["phoneNumber'] = newPhoneNumberResult.PhoneNumber` to edit a setting that already exists. [Isolated Storage Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)